# how do I generate a test file form a java file using Parasoft

Tags: java, junit, parasoft, jtest

I am new at Parasoft. I am using Parasoft as a plugin for Eclipse. Today I used it for the first time on a java file with right click and **Parasoft**->**Test Using**->**User-Defined**->**my_configuration.**

How do I generate a new test file for a java file using Parasoft?
How do I modify a test file already created for a java file? I make some changes in a java file and I should modify the test file. 
I think there should be an option somewhere but I didn't founded on the web. 
Something in Parasoft/Test Using/Builtin?

If I go to "Parasoft -> Test Using -> Builtin -> Generate and Run Unit Tests" I can generate a new test file for my java file. 
But I want to add test cases automatically to my existing test file.
In my header of test file I have:
 * Created by Jtest on 10/2/12 9:07:30 AM.
 * Updated by Jtest on 10/25/12 2:35:22 PM, 12 test cases added.

I need to update this file like in the second line from above"* Updated by Jtest on 10/25/12 2:35:22 PM, 12 test cases added.".

Thanks,

Dorian

Answer (score 0):

The automation for test class creation is configured in `Test Configuraion` tab `Generaiton`.

More you will find in the help, that is very outstanding and all required information are there. The lesson 11 should answer to all of your question.

Comment: If I go to "Parasoft -> Test Using -> Builtin -> Generate and Run Unit Tests" I generate a new test file for my java file. 
But I want to add test cases to my existing test file. 
In my header of test file I have:
 * Created by Jtest on 10/2/12 9:07:30 AM.
 * Updated by Jtest on 10/25/12 2:35:22 PM, 12 test cases added.

 I need to update this file like in the second line from above"* Updated by Jtest on 10/25/12 2:35:22 PM, 12 test cases added.". 
 
 Thanks,
 
 Dorian